# AzureAD Enterprise Application SAML2.0 Metadata file doesn't include additionnal claims

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, metadata, saml, saml-2.0

When I edit the claims in my SAML Azure Enterprise application, the metadata file never changes.

I tried to rename the attribute `emailAddress` to `email`, then saving the claims, but they never update in the XML file.

My service provider keeps telling me to update my metadata file, but I can't seem to find anything in the UI to refresh it.

I tried generating a new certificate, but it didn't change the XML file (except the certificate signature maybe).

How can I force Azure to update my app's metadata so I can provide a complete file with claims to my SP ?

Answer (score 0):

It's not supported to see the custom claims added to the app on Azure Portal in the metadata file currently.

There is a PS / Graph API approach (in preview) for customizing claims: [Claims mapping policy assignment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-claims-mapping#claims-mapping-policy-assignment).

See a similar question [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/23405).